# What does "IsDlg=1" means? - SharePoint Site

Tags: c#, post, sharepoint

I stumbled open this link:

```
POST /somewhere/_Layouts/AComponent/Page.aspx?IsDlg=1 HTTP/1.1
```

What does IsDlg=1 means at the end?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to solve this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045759/send-post-request-from-c-sharp-to-sharepoint-site-aspx). Hopefully your answer to "IsDlg=1" will give me some clue to solve my problem.

Comment: http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/

Comment: I tried that link but my workplace has many websites blocked and I cannot view that page...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a SharePoint problem, rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a feature on every  SharePoint page that allows you to hide the header and nav on the page by simply appending isdlg=1 to the end of the URL

So basically, in SharePoint 2010, you can add a query string parameter “IsDlg” to the URL to hide page’s top and left navigation.

You can check more detailed descriptions [here](http://davidlozzi.com/2014/10/28/sharepoint-hiding-ribbon-and-more-with-isdlg/) and [here](http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/)

Comment: worth pointing out here that it is case sensitive! `IsDlg != isdlg` https://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/

Answer (score 2):

taken from [We all know what IsDlg does… wait, what the…??](http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/)

> Don’t know what IsDlg is? It’s a little query string parameter that
>   SharePoint uses to hide elements on your page using CSS.

....

> when the IsDlg parameter is sent to the page as a parameter in the
>   query string, it hides everything on the page with a CSS class of
>   s4-notdlg.

but mainly, IsDlg hides the header and nav on the page (preventing scrolling)

also note passing IsDlg vs isdlg (case sensitive!) you get different behavior.